# How to use Affinity Collocation where same key needs to refereed twice in SQL create command Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite

How to refer the same key twice in the table for affinity Collocation?

A) Following is my scenario User table with fields

1. Id
2. First Name
3. Last Name
   .
   ...
   N

B) I have a legal entity table with columns

1. LE id
2. LE Code -> Need to refer ID field of the user Table
3. LE Country  -> Need to refer the field for the user table

B) I have a currency table with columns

1. Currency Code
2. CreatedBy  -> Need to refer ID field of the user Table
3. Last Modified by  -> Need to refer ID field of the user Table
4. LEid -> Need to refer LE id field of the user Table.

I want to achieve this using SQL create a command for ignite. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can only collocate table by a single field (or a single distinct fields tuple).

In this case it seems that you can collocate everything by user ID. Maybe you will need to denormalize this field so that it is present in all tables.

Comment: Thank you alamar Currency table has relation to user and legal entity table.I am wondering  is collection possible with complex objects.

Comment: You can make smaller tables REPLICATED - they need no collocation. You can also split table to two, one collocated to join user and other collocated to join legal entity. That's about it.